# Cancel button dissapears on Google Chrome with new OS X Yosemite 10.10

Tags: c, google-chrome, browser

I have no idea how to fix this but it has been happening since I updated my OS on my Macbook Pro. Whenever I upload an image or browse files in Google Chrome the Cancel and Upload buttons are outside the screen. Even resizing my browser window to the smallest it can get, as in the picture, still hides the buttons below the screen.

What am I missing? Is there some setting I need to change? I've tried selecting different file viewing options with still the same results.

[image: full size shot of my computer screen with resized browser window and buttons outside of the screen.]

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and found this on stackoverflow->

https://superuser.com/questions/829397/how-can-i-resize-the-open-file-dialog-in-chrome-for-osx

Resize the entire window with constraints using command+shift while moving either edge of the window.

Comment: Still not a single solution on there solved my problem.